# Modifying cross account subscription created in SQS account

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a SQS in account A which is subscribed to SNS in account B. Following the AWS doc, I created the subscription in account A i.e the Queue's account. 
AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-message-to-sqs-cross-account.html

I need to modify the subscription to enable raw message delivery.

I am not able to find any doc explaining how to modify the subscription if it is created in the Queue owner's account.

is it possible to modify the subscription? If not, what is the way to proceed?

Comment: I would suggest going to the SNS management console in Account-B and modifying the subscription that you should see there.

Comment: see this example https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/b691e46e57a3e24477e6a5fa2e849da44db7002f/sdk/src/Services/SimpleNotificationService/Custom/AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient.Extensions.cs